# authentication for npm install during PuTTY ssh?

Tags: ssh, firewall, suse, npm

I'm connected via PuTTY ssh to a Linux Server (so it's not supposed to have a GUI).

when I `npm install` something, due to some intranet network configuration, the http request is redirected as follows

```
npm i express
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for http://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN: request to https://auth-fw-dc.mycompany.com:nnnn/php/uid.php?...&url=http://registry.npmjs.org%2fexpress failed
```

Of course the `SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN` derives from the redirection to our firewall authentication web portal.

I guess it is a wrong network configuration in our intranet and the http request from npm should not be redirected to our company's firewall especially because I can't open a browser from ssh to authenticate myself there: am I guessing right or is it something I can configure on this machine with some **SSH** Linux commands for npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently solved after clearing the npm cache

```
rm ./package-lock.json
rm -r ./node_modules
npm cache clear --force
```

and having reconfigured the https connection but without check.

```
npm set strict-ssl false
```

and

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

or equivalently

```
npm config rm registry
```

(not sure if anything else was done by the network team after I wrote to them)

In conclusion, in my intranet scenario, the issue was due to the following http setting (initial tried to circumvent the ssl issue, see for example [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796030/11323942))

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and solved by removing that wrong command, as said above.